# Add to the end of a line missing a pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, awk

I have a long, not well maintained bash script on CentOS, with many log lines using echo, and about of third of them tee-ing into a log file. I would like to modify the rest of the echo lines to also tee into this log file.

Here is an example myscript.sh:

```
command1
echo "hi1"
echo "hi2" | tee -a my.log
echo "hi3 tee"
command2
```

After running something on this file, I would like the contents to be changed to:

```
command1
echo "hi1" | tee -a my.log
echo "hi2" | tee -a my.log
echo "hi3 tee" | tee -a my.log
command2
```

I am thinking that I need to use sed or awk with a regular expression, where the logic is, "if the line contains '`echo`', followed by *not* '`| tee`', then append ' `| tee -a my.log`' at the end of the line".

After a lot of searching, this is the best I've come up with so far:

```
sed --in-place=_BACKUP '/^.*echo\(?!\| tee$\)*/ s/$/ \| tee -a my.log/' myscript.sh
```

But this just appends `| tee -a my.log` to the end of each line containing `echo`.

Does anyone have any good ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick *(although I feel a bunch of corner cases coming)*:

```
$ awk '/^echo/&&!/tee -a my.log$/{$0=$0"| tee -a my.log"}1' file
command1
echo "hi1"| tee -a my.log
echo "hi2" | tee -a my.log
echo "hi3 tee"| tee -a my.log
command2
```

**Explanation:**

```
/^echo/                  # If the line start echo
&&                       # Logical AND
!/tee -a my.log$/        # Doesn't end with tee -a my.log
{$0=$0"| tee -a my.log"} # Append the tee command to the end of the line
1                        # Awk idiom to print all the lines in the file
```

Answer (score 2):

It's actually better to open an fd for the file and use a function to log the messages e.g.

```
exec 40>>my.log

function log {
    echo "$1"
    echo "$1" >&40
}

command1
log "hi1"
log "hi2"
log "hi3"
command2

exec 40>&-
```

Your script would actually run faster that way and would no longer require you to keep calling tee.

A command like this could be a start to convert the files to that:

```
sed '/echo /{ s@ \?| \?tee -a my.log@@; s@echo @log @; }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just learned a bit of `awk` and feel great! Wrote this and tested on the sample input:

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ "^echo" && $0 !~ "tee -a") \
        print $0" | tee -a my.log"; \
      else \
        print $0}' myscript.sh

Where
$0    #means the current line of input
~     #match the following regex
!~    #not match the following regex
```

As sudo_O said, there might be many edge cases that fails the program.